# How to check if parent is present or not?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two situations:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="content">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="content">TEXT</div>
```

I want to change text color if class parent is present or not.

I write this css but it doesn't work:

```
div:not(.parent) > .content{
 color: blue;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because in the second example you have no `div` element wrapping the content so `div:not(.parent)` is not matched (`.content` is a direct child of the `body` element)

Either you write

```
:not(.parent) > .content {
   color: blue;
}
```

([without defining the element](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daNgVv)) or just reverse your logic: give a basic style for `.content` in case there's no parent element and override the style if the `.parent` exists:

```
.content {
  color: blue; /* no .parent */
}

.parent > .content{
  color: inherit;
}
```